# ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 Issues hosting application in IIS 8

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I published ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 application in file system from Visual studio 2015 and then I copied over that code to IIS server and configured accordingly as per this [link](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html).

I created a website and pointed it to wwwroot folder as per instructions in above link.

When I browse the site, I get 404 in IE browser. So what I did is I turned on logging in web.config file which is under wwwroot folder. I set the value of stdoutLogEnabled to true `stdoutLogEnabled="true"`. And then I tried to browse the site in browser again. In the logs folder, I can able to see that it is listening on 31581 port. But when I browse `http://localhost/website_name` that is hosted in IIS, I get 404. So I looked at the event logs and I get error related to `HttpPlatformHandler`. Please see below event log as well.

**Standard out log:**

```
Hosting environment: Production
Now listening on: http://localhost:31581
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

**Event logs:**

```
The description for Event ID 1001 from source HttpPlatformHandler cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

Process '4784' started successfully and is listening on port '28688'.
```

Could this be a known issue? I looked at several articles and they say to uninstall and reinstall `HttpPlatformHandler`. I also rebooted the server to see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: what happens when you navigate to http://localhost:31581 ? The issue is binding to port 80 where you are navigating to browse your site whereas the site is hosted on 31581 and you can change that in IIS or by configuration

Comment: I am able to browse with `localhost:31581`. I believe application generates that automatically when you browse the site via IIS.

Comment: You need to modify the bindings in IIS. Also please look into the launchsettings.json in the properties folder to configure the port number for IIS Express or the configuration you are using

Comment: After updating port bindings in launchsettings.json file I was able to browse the application :)

Comment: @LexLi I posted that as an answer as that worked for Ray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ray acknowledged in comment above, solution is to modify the port setting in the  launchsettings.json file from port 31581 to 80.