# ASP.NET 5 host application in IIS 8 with https bindings

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core-mvc

Earlier I was having issue hosting ASP.NET 5 application in IIS and now I am able to host it via http. Here is my [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34773926/asp-net-5-mvc-6-issues-hosting-application-in-iis-8) that contains details.

For past couple days I have been trying to enable https for my application over port 443. In launchSetting.json file I updated `iisexpress` settings to `"applicationUrl": "https://servername:443/"` with valid certificate. but I still get 404 error when I browse the application in the browser.

**Here is my launchSettings.json file:**

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://servername:443/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "Hosting:Environment": "Development"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "commandName": "web",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "Hosting:Environment": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Here is my project.json file:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Net.Http.Server": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "dnx-clr-win-x64": "1.0.0-rc1-update1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  }
```

**Startup.cs file:**

```
public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc()              // Add MVC Dependency.
                .AddJsonOptions(
                    opt =>
                    {
                        opt.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(); // Api convert all property names to CamelCase.
                    }
                );
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory LoggerFactory)
        {
            LoggerFactory.AddDebug(LogLevel.Warning);
            app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(config =>
            {
                config.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "App", Action = "Index" }
                    );
            }); // Use MVC from Dependency.
        }

        // Entry point for the application.
        public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
    }
```

I am not sure if it is right way to enable https in the application, but IIS bindings are configured correctly with valid certificate. So I am not sure why it is still throwing 404 error.

Any help from community is really appreciated. :)

Comment: drop the port # component from the url. https emplies 443.

Comment: I tried that as well, but didn't work. :(

Comment: For our deployments there really isn't anything specific in the MVC project. we simply bind them to an ssl port(s) through IIS.  The only gotchas I have come across is IIS handling a request because a given MVC path matched a physical folder Ex /Styles/.  Try creating a template MVC project, publish it, and only do the ssl binding in IIS.

Comment: @pnm - I tried your suggestion before opening this question to community. It appears ASP.NET 5 hosting is not simple as lower version of ASP.